# How to secure imap_open connection

Tags: php, imap

i use imap_open() to establish a connection with my mailserver for checking bounced emails.

```
$pop3conn  = imap_open('{localhost:110/pop3}', MAILLOGIN, MAILPWD);

if($pop3conn == false)
echo'<br />no conn';
else
{
    // check mail headers and bodies
}
```

I get a PHP Notice about insecure authentication:

> Notice: Unknown: SECURITY PROBLEM: insecure server advertised
>   AUTH=PLAIN (errflg=1) in Unknown on line 0

I have searched on php.net and googled for hours, but can't find a solution how to get rid of this.

the only thing i found did also not work: adding /secure to the servername.

```
$pop3conn  = imap_open('{localhost:110/pop3/secure}', MAILLOGIN, MAILPWD);
```

then i get:

> Notice: Unknown: Can't do secure authentication with this server
>   (errflg=2) in Unknown on line 0

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: insecure with auth=plain means that it's a plaintext unencrypted connection, sending your username/password in-the-clear. If you're not worried about either being sniffed while in transit, you can ignore the warning. Otherwise you'll have to switch to pop3s, which is pop3-over-ssl. But for that to work, the server has have pop3s enabled.

Comment: @marc B, i cant set your comment as accepted answer, because you have put your answer as a comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a little surprised this is giving you `in Unknown on line 0` as this normally only happens when the error occurs before the script begins to execute - however, the only real solution to this problem is to hide PHP errors.

It looks as though the server you are connecting to doesn't support secure authentication, and the only solution to this is to ask the server administrator to support it. Or to use a different server. There is nothing you can do in your code to work around that particular problem, so you will just have to handle the error instead of trying to fix it (much as I hate to recommend that approach to anyone for anything).

You may find that even calling `ini_set('display_errors', 0)` or using the evil `@` operator won't fix this, since it is `in Unknown on line 0` - although you shouldn't be showing PHP errors in a production environment anyway. You should ensure that your php.ini in production is set to hide errors from the user.

Comment: or simply use `@imap_open('{localhost:110/pop3}', MAILLOGIN, MAILPWD);` I don't like errors in general not to show up

Answer (score 2):

It's not really a bogus message, it just means that it's a plaintext unencrypted connection.
Here is how you can do :

```
$error = imap_errors();
if (count($error) > 1 || $error[0] != 'SECURITY PROBLEM: insecure server advertised AUTH=PLAIN') {
  // More than 1 error or not the expected error
  var_dump($error);
  throw new Exception('IMAP error detected');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is few year old but I came across with the same issue:

```
imap_open("{imap.domain.com:143}INBOX", 'username', 'password');
```

gaves me error `SECURITY PROBLEM: insecure server advertised AUTH=PLAIN`.

So, it says I am sending the credentials unsecured. All I had to do is to go to my mail provider to find out any other way how to connect securely.

Standard ports are:

```
Protocol      Unsecured      Secured
POP3          110            995 (SSL, TLS)
IMAP4         143            993 (SSL, TLS)
SMTP          25             465 (SSL), 587 (TLS, STARTTLS)
```

And according to the documentation of PHP function [imap_open()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-open.php) I have modified the parameters as followed:

```
imap_open("{imap.domain.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX", 'username', 'password');
```

So now I have the communication encrypted/secured and PHP does not report  errors any more.