# imap_mail_move only works without CP_UID

Tags: php, imap

**Main Question**

I've been building a custom IMAP class (testing/using locally on XAMPP), but for some reason when I want to use the function `imap_mail_move` whilst trying to preserve the UID with the `CP_UID` flag, messages do not seem to get move what-so-ever, however, removing the flag it works perfectly.

I call the function below:

```
return @imap_mail_move($this->stream, $messageNumber, $folder, CP_UID);
```

IMAP is successfully connected (though always getting the `SECURITY PROBLEM: insecure server advertised AUTH=PLAIN (errflg=1)` error on line 0 and the message number and the moving to folder are correctly defined.

Remove the `@` reveals no clues as to why it is not working, same goes for adding `or die('error!')` to the end - it's like it functions but does nothing.

Destruct function in the class exists with the below (so it closes the IMAP connection and does expunging):

```
@imap_close($this->stream, CL_EXPUNGE);
```

**Further IMAP Questions**

I save all emails within an MySQL database for faster processing, custom processing, searching, etc. However, I've noticed that some issues could occur where one moves messages within Outlook (etc).

What is the best way to update the message's UID - since I store this in the database for quick access, but can change if a message were to move. Or is there a better function to use using something more unique to get `message numbers/UID` when moving/deleting/flagging emails? I had originally thought that UIDs did not change (as lead to believe at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-uid.php), but it seems that they actually do.

Also, is it possible to get the new UID after moving a message?

Comment: UIDs are immutable as long as they're in one folder.  If you move them to a new folder, it's a new message with a new UID.  UIDs are also only unique per folder.

Answer (score 1):

CP_UID only indicate that $messageNumber contains an UID and not a sequenceNumber. The error message, I belive, is not realated to moving email. It only states a security issue whit your password send as plain text.

You cannot preserve the old UID. Each mailbox has it's own UID. UID are not unique between mailbox (only in the same mailbox). I believe you can't also assign yourself the UID (not directly whit PHP for sure).

For the rest, I am in the same situation as you.

I am currently thinking of using http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-status.php. Whit this function you can get the next planned UID. However, if two person is moving a email in the same mailbox at the same time it could create a problem.

I don't know either how to update the database whenever someone move an email from a third party client like outlook.

Comment: Here is two other question regarding your error message : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9034854/how-to-secure-imap-open-connection and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766203/suppress-bogus-php-imap-open-notice-insecure-server-advertised-auth-plain.